# How to disable calendar extender?

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net

Is it possible to disable calendar extender from code behind? If yes how? 
I want to prevent calendar from popping up even if a user clicks withing the textbox when certain conditions are met.

Answer (score 0):

I'll try doing this on the client side javascript:

```
  function HidePopUp() {
      document.getElementById('calenderExtender1').style.display = "none";
    }
```

In form load of the page you add a click event which will tri

```
    txtDate1.Attributes.Add("OnClick", "HidePopUp()");
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Jquery to create the calendar you can just remove the `hasDatepicker` class from the textbox:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   TextBox1.CssClass = TextBox1.CssClass.Replace("hasDatepicker", "");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you dont care about being able to manually edit the date, setting

```
TextBox1.Enabled = false
```

will cause the calendar popup to not appear when you click the textbox.
One side effect is that the textbox will appear disabled.